# How I can prevent indentation after a line starting with a number?

Tags: vim, restructuredtext, word-wrap

I've an issue with indentation in RestructuredText in vim.

When I'm writing RestructuredText (filetype=rst), vim puts some spaces after a line that starts with a digit:

```
vim puts some space after line starting with a digit like even in mid sentence
9 something things are working and doing something and I need a new line to
  prove my point
```

I get this everytime I indent the current paragraph (gqip)

Is there any way I can prevent the spaces in front of "prove" ?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this, but this looks like a combination of

```
:set formatoptions+=n formatlistpat=^\\d\\+\\s\\+
```

I would fix this by correcting `'formatlistpat'`; it should only recognize numbers formatted like `1.` or `1)` (the default does), not simple digits.

Use `:verbose set formatlistpat?` to check where this got set, and then either change that, or override for the RST filetype in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/rst.vim`.

Comment: No idea about hanging indent after a digit alone, but hanging indent after a digit or a `#` at the beginning of line _followed by a dot_ (i.e. `9.` and `#.`) is handled in the `indent/rst.vim` file, and it can't be disabled (not without giving up on `rst` indentation altogether, that is).  Presumably `9.` and `#.` start enumerations.